# A strange condition for a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

I was studying a GRE-like test and came across the following task:

> Suppose $f(x, y)$ is defined everywhere at $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $$\forall \ x, y \ \rightarrow \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{f(ax, ay)}{a} = x + y$$ then
>
> A. $f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$
>
> B. $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$
>
> C. There are partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial y}$ at every points of some neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$
>
> D. The function $g(x) = f(x, 0)$ is differentiable at $x = 0$ and $g'(0) = 0$
>
> E. A-D are false

Honestly, I don't understand what that condition means. Does it mean that $f(x, y) = g(x+y)$, where $g(x) \sim x, x\to 0\ $?

I understand that B is false because otherwise A and C will be also true (I realize that it's not a rigorous proof, but only considerations)

Could you please give me any hints for this task? Thank you a lot in advance!

(A textbook says that E is true)

Comment: I would start with an example function $f(x,y)=x+y$ and would try to see which of A-E are valid for that function. Then I would try to prove the ones that are valid, this time for all functions satisfying the above condition.

Comment: @user8734617 $x+y$ is a very good function which satisfies all A-D conditions, if I don't mistake. I've forgotten to mention that the textbook said that E is true, so the task become more easy - to think up counter examples but this condition seems strange and I can't understand it totally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x+y+\sin\left(\frac{y^4}{x}\right), &x\neq 0\\
y, &x=0\end{cases}.$$
Observe that for each $x\neq 0$, we have
$$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{f(ax,ay)}{a}=x+y+\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{a^3y^4}{x}\right)}{a}=x+y$$
For $x=0$, we have
$$f(ax,ay)=ay$$
Thus clearly $f(x,y)$ satisfies the condition given. However it's easy to see that conditions A-D fail to satisfy:

A: Consider the curve $y^4=x$, and approach $(0,0)$ along this curve, we obtain the directional limit
$$\lim_{y\to 0}y^4+y+\sin\left(\frac{y^4}{y^4}\right)=\sin(1)\neq 0.$$
Thus $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Similarly you can prove that B-D also fail.

Comment: thank you a lot! So, that condition didn't mean smth well-treated and the task only aimed to come up with such elegant functions as you mentioned?

Comment: @DF Exactly! Sometimes things don't behave as what they look like.

Comment: yes, that's true :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider $$f(x,y) = x +y + \frac{y^2}{x}$$ and just define $f(0,y)$ as you please.
It's easy to see these are all false.